# AngularJs Directive Controller/pre/post:what is the difference between set the data for directive instance/child elements and manipulate/access DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to understand the compile and link phase of angularjs directive through some tutorial.

After compile phase the directive instance gets created. In link phase the order of execution of function is

```
Controller
Pre
Post
```

In `pre link` function I read a statement ***"Its safe to set data and even child data but not safe to manipulate DOM instance"***

Again in `post link` function ***"safe to manipulate DOM instance but not safe to set data for child"***

Now I am not able to understand the difference between setting the data and manipulation of DOM instance and also why it is not safe??

What I understand is manipulation of DOM instance is basically playing around with the data `(scope binding {{}})` whether it is directive or its child.

I am really getting confused , can anybody help me to understand the difference between the two . It will be a great help if some one explain with a proper example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This becomes much more clear if you imagine several directives:

```
<parent>
  <child child-value="v1"></child>
  <child child-value="v2"></child>
</parent>
```

1. If you want to initialize v1 and v2 in parent - you should do it in controller/pre-link. (Usuall pre- is not used)
   But you should not manipulate DOM - cause it may be modified by child directive.
2. In post - it is useless to set v1 and v2 - children are already inited. But it is safe to manipulate DOM - since it is in final state.